# R keep rows with at least one column greater than value

Tags: r, subset

Say I have a data frame with a few hundred rows and a few hundred columns. How would I keep rows that have at least one value greater than 10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to construct the condition in base R:

```
df[rowSums(df > 10) >= 1, ]
```

---

with `dplyr` (0.7.0), now you can use `filter_all` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
filter_all(df, any_vars(. > 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another option:

```
df[apply(df>10,1,any),]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` with `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `>`, 10)), ]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:12, 5*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```